# Convert two lists in to dictionary in dart programming flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert two arrays in to a dictionary. i have two dynamic lists after that i need to combine two lists as dictionary(map)

```
var x = ["car", "train", "bus"];
var y = ["https://car", "https://train", "https://bus"]

Expected:
 final Map<String, String> z = ["car": "https://car", "train": "https://train", "bus": "https://bus"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, although I'm sure there are cleaner ways out there:

```
var z = new Map<String, String>(); 

for( var i = 0; i <= x.length; i++ ) { 
  z[x[i]] = y[i]; 
}
```

Additionally, look into the [putIfAbsent](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html) function, as it may come in handy if you need to add more key/value pairs

Comment: Hi, In output i am getting value as null;  flutter: {car: null, train: null, bus: null}

Comment: Go ahead and see my edit, I made a small mistake :P

Comment: I doesn't need any for loop which will make little confusing.

instead use **Map.fromIterables(List 1, List 2);**                        
and  **map["item1 in list 1"]** will give the corresponding value in **list 2**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *factory constructor* `fromIterables` from the class `Map` to pass any number of iterables.

Here is a working example:

```
var x = ["car", "train", "bus"];
var y = ["https://car", "https://train", "https://bus"]

final Map<String, String> z = Map.fromIterables(x, y);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simple one that you are looking for (I know I'm late but it will help others)

```
 List<String> letters = ['b', 'c'];
 List<String> words = ['bad', 'cat'];

 Map<String, String> map = new Map.fromIterables(letters, words);
 map['b'] + map['c'];  // badcat
```

(This snippet is from gitHub: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/04b7b090eb5dd714654faa80843c1feadc1ccede/sdk/lib/core/map.dart#L304)